# Minimal transitive set

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

The question is as below:

Let $ X $ be a set and denote $ X_{0} = X $, $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ :
$ X_{n+1} = \bigcup X_n $.
Using separation axiom, union axiom (by ZF), and recursion, we create the set:
$ Y = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n $. Prove that $ Y $ is a transitive set.

I know that it is proved by using induction, but I couldnt figure what I need to use induction on. I thought maybe when I start with n = 0, the claim will be for the union of $X_0, X_1$ and but then I'm confused about the required assumption for at the step.

I would like to have some idea. Thanks

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think there is induction in this proof.

Comment: You're right, thanks.

Comment: While induction is not needed to prove that $Y$ is transitive, induction is used to prove that it is the smallest (so, a minimum, not just minimal) transitive set containing $X$. To see that, suppose that $Z$ is a transitive set and $X\subseteq Z$, by induction we can now show that if $X_n\subseteq Z$, then $X_{n+1}\subseteq Z$, and we can therefore conclude that $Y\subseteq Z$.

Comment: That was the next question and I realized the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A\in Y$. Then $A\in X_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. And if $a\in A$ then $a\in\bigcup X_n$. And $\bigcup X_n=X_{n+1}$. Hence $a\in X_{n+1}$.  And as $n+1\in\mathbb{N}, a\in Y$. Hence $Y $ is transitive.